# Mysql help in update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

> status: TINYINT
>
> locked_by: INTEGER
>
> date: DATETIME
>
> page: TINYINT
>
> my_id: BIGINTEGER
>
> PRIMARY KEY IS (page, my_id)

and have the following indexes:

> INDEX idx_col_lock_status (locked_by, status),
>
> INDEX idx_my_id (my_id)

At some point we have the following rows:

```
status, locked_by, date, page, my_id

2       243        NULL  0     1
0       0          NULL  1     1
1       244        NULL  2     1
2       255        NULL  0     2
2       2556       NULL  1     2
2       255        NULL  2     2
```

I would like to **update** all rows (set status = 0, locked_by = )
 that have their **status value !=  2 or**

they have **status value = 2** **but** there is

another row with the **same** my_id that has **status != 2**

After the above update the above rows should become.

```
status, locked_by, date, page, my_id

0       0          NULL  0     1   --note this line
0       0          NULL  1     1
0       0          NULL  2     1   --and this line
2       255        NULL  0     2
2       2556       NULL  1     2
2       255        NULL  2     2
```

I am using Mysql version 5.1.63.

Thanks

Comment: Yes I am sure , check how the rows should be after the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tt(my_id int);
INSERT INTO tt SELECT my_id FROM yourTable WHERE status != 2);

UPDATE yourTable yt
SET yt.status = 0, yt.locked_by = 0
WHERE status != 2
OR 
(status = 2 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tt WHERE yt.my_id = tt.my_id));

DROP TABLE tt;
```

You have to work with a temporary table here, because you can't use the same table for update and a subquery.